# Why does Chrome on Windows 7 not show certain Unicode characters to me?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

This [Apple question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21804/what-is-this-key) contains the text

> what is this key? ⎋

Which looks like this to me in Google Chrome:

[image]

Why is that Unicode character, or others like it, undisplayable in Google Chrome on Windows 7?

Comment: It looks like a box to me... In any case, double posting is frowned upon.

Comment: @soandos what other post are you talking about? also, it isn't supposed to be a box. that's why I'm asking the question.  Someone asked a question on askdifferent and typed a unicode character there, but on my install of Chrome I see the generic box.

Comment: As do I... It appears it is not an issue with your chrome install, it is for all chromes. FF recognizes it fine. Chrome cannot even recognize it as a Unicode charachter (I don't think).

Comment: Interestingly, Chromium on Ubuntu does just fine.

Comment: @soandos Works fine for me with Google Chrome (12.0.742.112) on Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty).

Answer (score 20):

I'm assuming it's a font substitution issue.

The browsers are encountering the problem of "The selected glyph is not in the specified font". There are two directions you can go from here: you can either pull the equivalent glyph out of another font (which will often look broken but it may not be clear *why* to the user) or just display a character-not-found placeholder (which will always look broken, but at least obviously so).

I imagine Firefox and Opera recognise that the glyph being requested is a symbol that is safe to pull from another font, while the remaining browsers are being conservative and just showing the "Uh... dunno" glyph.

Comment: I believe Chrome and Safari both use Windows GDI for text rendering on Windows.  IE9 uses DirectWrite which appears to have the same behavior as GDI in this case.

Comment: Interesting: You get the same result if you paste it into the address bar.

Comment: @xpda you're right; the character works in the address bar *and* the body on Firefox, and does not work in either place in Chrome. Fascinating.

Comment: Sounds about right: Chrome and Firefox both use [Uniscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniscribe) to render text in-browser, and Uniscribe just returns an error code to the calling application when a particular character can't be found in the current font. It's up to the application to decide whether Uniscribe should then use font fallback to find a substitution, or whether it should just render the box glyph. Chrome is one of the browsers that just says "Whatever, I don't care. Box is fine."

Answer (score 11):

Interesting. It's not just Chrome -- you might well ask why *any* of the following browsers can't display it on Windows 7:

[image]

From top to bottom:

- Firefox (y)
- IE9 (n)
- Chrome (n)
- Opera (y)
- Safari (n)

Therefore, Firefox and Opera can display this unicode character in Windows 7, but the other browsers cannot.

> what is this key? ⎋

Comment: For what is worth, that key is "ESC" in Mac OS X.

Comment: @jjn it's a partial answer, which is generally allowed

Comment: Noted. (Comment withdrawn.)

Comment: How alike browsers are this days... :)

Comment: Chrome 13.0.782.107/Linux: ok

Answer (score 6):

The question asking "Why is that Unicode character, [...] undisplayable in Google Chrome on Windows 7?" is the

That particular character is simply a unicode codepoint which is an arbitrary number. There are a lot of unicode codepoints that do not have an 'official' symbol. Even if they do have a symbol, it is not necessarily the case that your font has a symbol for that codepoint. If you choose a different font, you may end up with a different symbol.

I looked at the CSS for the page and it shows this character displaying in Arial (plus a bunch of other fonts that do not matter). Windows comes with Arial so it should always pick up that font first. It looks like Arial does **not** have a symbol for that unicode codepoint. Anytime you do not have a glyph for a codepoint, it puts in some form of a box indicating there is no glyph (as others have indicated).

The bigger question is, what exactly is Firefox or the other browsers doing where it works on Windows. I looked at the other fonts listed in the CSS (I thought it may be falling back on the next CSS font) but they also do not have a glyph for that codepoint. One possibility is that Firefox actually ships with its own fonts.

Digging into firefox, I did notice some fonts for math symbols here: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\res\fonts'. Perhaps this is where it is coming from.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit of an old question, but for those who are freshly Google'ing this, I have a solution that worked in 2013.  First, you must confirm that you have a font installed in your Windows 7 PC that can render the font:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/238b/index.htm

Assuming that at least one font in the Local Font List renders this:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%E2%8E%8B+-+Unicode+Character+%27BROKEN+CIRCLE+WITH+NORTHWEST+ARROW%27+%28U%2B238B%29

If not, then install a couple of "catch all" Unicode fonts: [Code2000](http://www.fontspace.com/james-kass/code2000) and [Symbola](http://shapecatcher.com/unicodefonts.html)

Once you have a font that'll render the symbol, you can try the browser test page:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/238b/browsertest.htm

Chrome 28.0.1500.95 (and probably all recent releases) performs font substitution ... mostly.

For whatever reason, even with fonts that render [U+1F3C1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f3c1/index.htm) correctly installed, Chrome 28.0 won't display this Unicode character: .  Firefox works beautifully.  Go figure.

- Dave

Comment: Font substitution above the BMP is still broken in Chrome for Windows **only**: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111382

Answer (score 2):

As per [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!) by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), "If there's no equivalent for the Unicode code point you're trying to represent in the encoding you're trying to represent it in, you usually get a little question mark: ? or, if you're really good, a **box**."

Im running Chromium 13.0.782.112 on Archlinux and my default encoding is en_US.UTF-8 -- the charcter displays fine on the originally linked page.

Comment: that's fine, but I don't think the question was about the box, but why some browsers can display this particular character and others cannot.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, agreed - if anything, my answer provides more supportive evidence re the typographical issue;  [read here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chromium#Font_Rendering). I can't tell you the default font as I'm not in front of my machine.

Answer (score 0):

**The actual answer:** It's because there's a bug in Chrome that borks Windows 7 (and higher?) unicode font rendering.

The issue is here, with all the gory details: https://crbug.com/42984 (star it and maybe somebody will notice it?)

More analysis and a possible workaround can be found here: http://gschoppe.com/uncategorized/fixing-unicode-support-in-google-chrome/ .

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 45.0 on my GNU/Linux LFS 7.9 didn't show the Unicode glyph mentioned in question, also didn't display other glyphs like greek etc.

However after downloading `Symbola` font from [here](http://www.fonts2u.com/symbola.font) and then:

```
~$ unzip Downloads/symbola.zip -d Downloads
~$ mv Downloads/Symbola/Symbola_hint.ttf .fonts
~$ fc-cache
```

Firefox now shows the glyph in question, and also displays other glyphs.